# match value from object to another array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello i have an array object i have to find values from object with match array keys
below is array and object i tried but not getting the result

```
var filterkey = [a,b,c];
var palistarray = [{
{
            "Id": 199,
            "a": "Rajesh Tamore",
            "b": "23/11/2022",
            "c": "23/11/2022",
            "d": "W"
        },
        {
            "Id": 200,
            "a": "Sunil N",
            "b": "21/11/2022",
            "c": "21/11/2022",
            "d": "S"
        },
}]
```

i want result like below

```
[{
{
            "a": "Rajesh Tamore",
            "b": "23/11/2022",
            "c": "23/11/2022",
        },
        {
            "a": "Sunil N",
            "b": "21/11/2022",
            "c": "21/11/2022",
        },
}]
```

i had tried below code

```
 palistarray.find((item,index) => {
    console.log(item[filterkey[index]]);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **Array.prototype.map()**, **Object.keys()** and **Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()** functions like this:

```
const result = palistarray.map((obj) => {
    const newObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (filterkey.includes(key) && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
    });
    return newObj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function, like this:

```js
const filterkey = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const palistarray = [
  {
    'Id': 199,
    'a':  'Rajesh Tamore',
    'b':  '23/11/2022',
    'c':  '23/11/2022',
    'd':  'W',
  }, {
    'Id': 200,
    'a':  'Sunil N',
    'b':  '21/11/2022',
    'c':  '21/11/2022',
    'd':  'S',
  },
]

const filterBy = (array, predicate) => array.map(value => {
  const result = {}

  predicate.forEach(key => {
    if (value[key]) {
      result[key] = value[key]
    }
  })

  return result
})

const result = filterBy(palistarray, filterkey)

console.log(result)
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I have to presume your array should be this, without the extra curly braces:

```
var palistarray = [{

            "Id": 199,
            "a": "Rajesh Tamore",
            "b": "23/11/2022",
            "c": "23/11/2022",
            "d": "W"
        },
        {
            "Id": 200,
            "a": "Sunil N",
            "b": "21/11/2022",
            "c": "21/11/2022",
            "d": "S"
       },
];
```

A really simple way would be this:

```js
const filterArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

const palistarray = [{

            "Id": 199,
            "a": "Rajesh Tamore",
            "b": "23/11/2022",
            "c": "23/11/2022",
            "d": "W"
        },
        {
            "Id": 200,
            "a": "Sunil N",
            "b": "21/11/2022",
            "c": "21/11/2022",
            "d": "S"
       },
];

const mapped = palistarray.map(item => {
  const data = {};
  filterArray.forEach(key => {
    data[key] = item[key];
  })
  return data;
});

console.log(mapped);
```

It's just a case of mapping and returning the specified keys from the objects